# Unit testing Reactive code in constructors using AutoMock from AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, system.reactive, autofixture

I'm hitting a bit of a chicken and egg problem setting up my mocks for Reactive Extensions code in a constructor. Here's the class under test (along with the service interface it depends on):

```cs
class MyViewModel
{
    public int Thing { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel(IMyService service)
    {
        service.StreamOfThings.Subscribe(x => Thing = x));
    }

    public void SomeClickEvent()
    {
        // Do something with `Thing`
    }
}
public interface IMyService
{
    IObservable<int> StreamOfThings { get; }
}
```

To make testing easier, I have also defined a custom attribute named `AutoMockData` I can use to use Moq to inject mock instances into my classes through AutoFixture:

```cs
public class AutoMockDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    private static IFixture Create() =>
        new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });
        
    public AutoMockDataAttribute() : base(Create) {}
}
```

With this, I am ready to write my test (using NUnit3):

```cs
[Test, AutoMockData]
public void Verify_some_behavior(
    [Frozen] Mock<IMyService> mockService,
    MyViewModel vm)
{
    mockService.Setup(x => x.StreamOfThings).Returns(Observable.Return(100));
    vm.SomeClickEvent();
    vm.Thing.Should().Be(100);
}
```

This test fails. I believe this fails because the constructor of `MyViewModel` sets up an observable pipeline on a different instance of `IObservable` than the one I set up in the unit test method.

The ideal solution here would be to use the `IObservable<>` instance that was set up using AutoFixture, but I'm not sure how to best do that. It would somehow need to already set up a pre-constructed pipeline for me.

The workaround I have found is to not use the `AutoMock` functionality of `AutoFixture` and instead construct a `Fixture` directly and directly use the `.Freeze()` and `.Create()` methods in the proper order. However, this leads to an arguably more difficult to read and less clean unit test body.

How can I continue to implement my test as shown here but also be able to set up any observables before they are used in the SUT's constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you never actually exercise the observable, so `Thing` keeps the value that AutoFixture assigned it on creation.

In the example below the `Subject` is frozen as an `IObservable<int>` which is then resolved as the return value for the `StreamOfThings`. Then the subject is forced to trigger the subscribers.

```cs
[Test, AutoMockData]
public void Verify_some_behavior(
    [Frozen(Matching.ImplementedInterfaces)] Subject<int> observable, 
    MyViewModel vm)
{
    observable.OnNext(100);
    vm.SomeClickEvent();
    vm.Thing.Should().Be(100);
}
```

The example is equivalent to the following:

```cs
[Test, AutoMockData]
public void Verify_some_behavior(
    Subject<int> observable,
    [Frozen] Mock<IMyService> mockService,
    MyViewModel vm)
{
    mockService.Setup(x => x.StreamOfThings).Returns(observable);

    observable.OnNext(100);
    vm.SomeClickEvent();

    vm.Thing.Should().Be(100);
}
```

This way of writing the test should also make it obvious how to handle multiple observable properties.

Comment: I'm still learning about AutoFixture. This is absolutely amazing. What do you do in scenarios of ambiguity? Like if an object implements multiple interfaces, or you have multiple `IObservable<int>` properties?

Comment: In case there would have been multiple observables, I would have probably created the subjects using AutoFixture and then would have used the Moq API to assign the observables explicitly.
My recommendation here is to start by using the imperative API offered by AutoFixture, and then look for ways to optimize the code by using the decorator (attribute) API.

Comment: When the same type implements multiple interfaces you could inject an object as a specific interface implementation. Usually this is equivalent to using the FrozenAttribute with matching by implemented interfaces or the direct base type.
`fixture.Inject<IObservable<int>>(new Subject<int>());`
Or you could relay entirely the creation of interfaces to concrete types
`fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(IObservable<>),typeof(Subject<>)));`
If these are not enough then you likely have a design flaw in your code.

Comment: Why doesn't the `Subject` have to be frozen in the second example? In my mind, the `mockService` instance will be constructed with *yet another* different implementation of `IObservable`. Am I wrong on this? If so, I don't understand why Frozen isn't necessary there.

Comment: In the first example `Subject` is frozen as all its implemented interfaces. So when the AutoFixture tries to resolve the value for `StreamOfThings` it finds the subject instance, thus the subject ends up in the service mock. By the way this happens because you chose to configure members in the `AutoMoqCustomization`.

In the second example I am manually instructing the service mock to return the value explicitly `mockService.Setup(x => x.StreamOfThings).Returns(observable);` so there is no reason to freeze the value.

Comment: Ah ok, so you are just using AutoFixture effectively as a raw `new` for the Subject type in the second case. That's interesting, I guess there's really never any reason to make those by hand you can just throw them in as an argument. Thank you!